# boost::variant implementation

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

I'm just curious about `boost::variant`'s implementation.

Does it work like this?

Two members:

1. A number representing the currently stored type (i.e. 0 for the first template parameter, 1 for the second template parameter etc)
2. A union of all possible types (which of course the size of the largest).

`apply_visitor()`:

Has a `switch` statement on the number representing the currently stored type to call the correct overload (this would in the worse case be compiled as jump table so take constant time).

I understand there's also there are a number of optimisations which can sure `boost::variant` does not need to dynamically allocate memory as detailed [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/variant/design.html#variant.design.never-empty.optimizations), but I think I get these.

Comment: You can actually look at the source code and maybe even the documentation might tell how it is implemented. I would expect a buffer (char array of sufficient type) and a tag to determine how to interpret the buffer.

Comment: Apologies in advance, but you've looked at the source, right?  You should be able to figure out exactly how it works, either by studying the sources, or building a test application and stepping through with a debugger, no?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works pretty much the way you described. Long story short:

1. It has an integer `which` that indicates which data type is used.
2. The storage is implemented using boost's `aligned_storage` which basically is a buffer of the maximum data size. (it is in a union, but for alignment purposes)

Finally, the visitor is indeed implemented with a `switch`, generated at compile time using macros to unroll for all type possibilities.